# Run CronExpression between specific times (but not on the hour)

Tags: sun-java6-jdk

I've seen quite a few questions here related to configuring CronExpressions. But they all seem to have exact hours (no minutes specified) as their time window for running.

Is there a way to configure a CronExpression to run say, every 5 minutes of every day between 7:37AM and 9:13PM? Configuring for 7AM - 9PM is simple. But I can't seem to figure out if there is a way (maybe it's not even supported) to run on a more detailed schedule.

I have an application that allows users to specify custom schedules. Right now I'm rounding up/down to the nearest "whole hour" as I cannot seem to figure out how to do specific times.

So for instance, this works

**0 0/5 2-16 ? * 1-7 //runs every 5 minutes between 2am and 4pm every day of the week**

So what would the expression be if I want to run:

**every 5 minutes between 2:19AM and 4:13PM?**

Or is this just not possible (outside of creating multiple CronExpressions and making it really messy imo)

Any help, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you enter `man 5 crontab` you will see the following example:-

> ```
>    # Run on every second Saturday of the month
>    0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 6 && echo "2nd Saturday"
> ```

Applying this to your case:-

```
   0 0/5 2-16 ? * 1-7  test $(date +\%R) \> 02:19 -a $(date +\%R) \< 16:13 && YourCommand
```

Alternatively, if `YourCommand` is a script, you can incorporate the time tests into it.

Note that, since the command is invoked at multiples of 5 minutes past the hour, tests for `>` and `>=` are equivalent (likewise `<` and `<=`); otherwise, you may need to adjust the test boundaries (eg `>= 02:18`), since `test` doesn't support `>=` and `<=` in string comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I probably should have mentioned that I'm doing this in Java. So I'm using the TriggerBuilder class which takes in a org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder object (which I pass in my "CronExpression" to). So the format of the example you sent me is invalid.

I'm about 3-4 days into working with this CronExpression format, had never even heard of it before :D Any tips on converting your example above to Java?

I'm wondering if I should monitor for the time window outside of the Trigger...and simply not create it until the start time..and then delete it after?

Comment: hmm...might have found the solution I'm looking for in Java.

Comment: In `cron` the command string is scheduled with a shell command, such as `bash -c 'test $(date +\%R) \> 02:19 -a $(date +\%R) \< 16:13 && YourCommand'` (according to your default shell), and `YourCommand` is any command that the shell recognises, including `java RunString`.